# Web API redirect to web page

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, asp.net-web-api2

I have a Web API that I need to convert to API Core 2. I have one issue I cannot seem to resolve. There is a redirect in the controller that uses `Request.CreateResponse` which does not appear to be available in .Net Core?

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get() {
    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Redirect);
    response.Headers.Location = new Uri("https://xxx.xxxx.com");
    return response;
}
```

Any idea how I can modify this to work?  Basically if a user does not pass any parameters, we just send them to a web page.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The syntax has changed in ASP.Net-Core. `HttpResponseMessage` is no longer used in action results. They will serialized like any other model returned object.

Use instead, the `Controller.Redirect` method which returns a `RedirectResult`

```
public IActionResult Get() {
    return Redirect("https://xxx.xxxx.com");
}
```

> ## RedirectResult
>
> RedirectResult will redirect us to the provided URL, it doesn’t matter if the URL is relative or absolute, it just redirect, very simple. Other thing to note is that it can redirect us temporarily which we’ll get 302 status code or redirect us permanently which we’ll get 301 status code. If we call the Redirect method, it redirect us temporarily...

Reference [Asp.Net Core Action Results Explained](http://hamidmosalla.com/2017/03/29/asp-net-core-action-results-explained)

Answer (score 3):

That's what the `Redirect()` method exactly does:

```
return Redirect("https://xxx.xxx.com");
```

But if you want more control, you can return a `ContentResult`:

```
response.Headers.Location = new Uri("https://xxx.xxx.com");
return new ContentResult {
  StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Redirect,
  Content = "Check this URL"
};
```

I don't see any benefit for doing this, though. Well, unless if you use some client that will not follow the redirect and you want to provide some instructions or content in the `Content` property, which the client will see as the body of the returned page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `HttpResponseMessage` instead, something like:

```
 var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Redirect);
 response.Headers.Location = new Uri("https://insight.xxx.com");
```